# Ошибка при использовании Glide совместно с GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter

Tags: android, gridview, glide

В своём приложении использую библиотеку [GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter). Эта библиотека расширяет возможности `GridView`, добавляя заголовок и футер.

В моём случае в основной части `GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter` отображаются `TextView`, в заголовке ничего нет, а в футере отображается ещё один `GridView` с изображениями (не `GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter`, а практически обычный `GridView` только немного модифицированный).

Для отображения изображений использую библиотеку `Glide` версии 3.8.0 и вполне обычную конструкцию адаптера. Всё работает отлично до тех пор пока не будет ситуации когда изображение по ссылке отсутствует. В `Glide` для таких ситуаций имеется метод `.error(R.drawable.image)`, отображающий картинку-заглушку.

Проблема заключается в том, что этот метод `.error()` не работает в футере `GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter`, при этом в основной части работает нормально. Также нормально работает, если вообще не использовать `GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter`.

После небольших тестов выяснил, что по каким-то причинам метод `getView` адаптера в таких ситуациях выполняется постоянно и не останавливается. Плюс ко всему имеющиеся изображения, из-за одного отсутствующего, загружаются гораздо дольше.

В итоге получается, что метод `.error()` не работает только в футере и в заголовке при использовании библиотеки `GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter`. Если все изображения имеются, то вообще никаких проблем не наблюдается.

Прошу подсказать как решить эту проблему? Что нужно исправить в моей ситуации?

На всякий случай код библиотеки GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter по [ссылке](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter/blob/master/src/in/srain/cube/views/GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter.java)

И код адаптера:

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
    private Context mContext;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private List<String> mObjects;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private ImageAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects)
        {
        super();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mObjects = objects;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
        {
        return mObjects.size();
        }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
        {
        return mObjects.get(position);
        }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
        {
        return position;
        }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
        if (convertView == null)
            {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);
            }

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Glide
            .with(mContext)
            .load("http://site.ru/" + getItem(position))
            .dontAnimate()
            .error(R.drawable.image_for_error)
            .into(imageView);

        return convertView;
        }
    }
```

**UPD**

- На всякий случай вместо `Glide` проверил другую библиотеку - `Picasso`, но эффект точно такой же.

Comment: А нельзя ли сразу поставить заглушку в самой разметке xml? а у же затем грузить в нее картинку??`Glide.with(context).load("url').into(imageView);` 
Если есть картинка, то она загрузится поверх заглушки, если нет, то отобразиться изначальная картинка xml-разметки. Может я и ошибаюсь.

Comment: @YaPV, к сожалению такой вариант не совсем подходит, т.к. пока идёт загрузка отображается круглый прогресс-бар. Просто я в коде его не показал, чтобы не захламлять его.

Comment: Так, а почему нельзя в разметку в корневой relativeLayout засунуть imageview(Visible.GONE) вместе с progressbar(Visible.VISIBLE)? Пока идет загрузка пусть прогрессбар крутиться себе на здоровье. Загрузка завершилась, меняем видимость элементов и глайдом грузим картинки в imageView. Там где картинка есть - она появится. Где картинки нет - будет стандартная drawable, которую изначально поставил в ImageView :) Мне кажется это самый простой метод

Comment: @YaPV, я вашу мысль понял. Для этого в `Glide` имеется метод `.listener()`, в котором можно отловить успешную загрузку или ошибку. Но при попытке менять видимость или проводить ещё какие-либо манипуляции, не происходит ничего. В вашем случае изображение-заглушка не появляется, а прогресс бар не исчезает.

Comment: Пишу на всякий случай, если вдруг кто-то столкнётся с проблемой. Пока дошёл до момента, что если отключить кеширование, то вообще никакая фотография не загружается. Именно поэтому картинка с ошибкой не загружается, т.к. она по факту в глейде разумеется не кешируется. Но почему при такой настройке фотографии не показываются, эту проблему ещё не решил.